# showing 2 prices wholesale and normal

Tags: php, plugins

am using the plugin Ignitewoo Wholesale price and have coded the single-product page to show two prices with the idea of one being the wholesale price the other normal retail price but atm its showing both wholesale price how can i change one to be only normal price?

```
    <p itemprop="price" class="price"><?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?> 
    <span class="pcat"><?php 
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    ?>
    trade
    <?php } else { ?> rrp <?php } ?>
</span></p>


<?php 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
?>
    <p itemprop="price" class="rrpprice"><?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?> <span class="pcat">rrp</span> </p> 
<?php } else { ?>  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read directly from the database so that no PHP interferes with it. using the postmeta field _price..

```
<?php echo woocommerce_price( get_post_meta( $product->id, '_price', true ) ) ?>
```

Comment: But dose any one now know how to add the Tax to it ?